# OpenVPN: Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: Operation not permitted

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, ubuntu-18.04, tun

I'm have some trouble with OpenVPN reccently, OpenVPN server are hosted on a VPS. It had been work for few months but last friday I reboot and update and upgrade since impossible to connect from my PC to the VPN server.

When I check log, there are this:

```
systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 11865.
systemd[1]: Stopped OpenVPN connection to server.
systemd[1]: Failed to set devices.allow on /system.slice/system-openvpn.slice/openvpn@server.service: Operation not permitted
systemd[1]: message repeated 2 times: [ Failed to set devices.allow on /system.slice/system-openvpn.slice/openvpn@server.service: Operation not permitted]
systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN connection to server...
ovpn-server[11903]: OpenVPN 2.4.4 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on May 14 2019
ovpn-server[11903]: library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018, LZO 2.08
systemd[1]: Started OpenVPN connection to server.
ovpn-server[11903]: ECDH curve prime256v1 added
ovpn-server[11903]: Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
ovpn-server[11903]: Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
ovpn-server[11903]: Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
ovpn-server[11903]: Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
ovpn-server[11903]: ERROR: Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: Operation not permitted (errno=1)
ovpn-server[11903]: Exiting due to fatal error
```

It seems that OpenVPN can't use TUN/TAP dev for no reason.

Anyone got a idea ? The problem is from the server, not the client (I guess)

Thanks,

Update:

```
         Icon name: computer-container
           Chassis: container
        Machine ID: bf6e72f90b6d4e1f94220c683fccc1fc
           Boot ID: ae58ef408533418a81641dbb52b363eb
    Virtualization: openvz
  Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-957.12.2.vz7.96.21
      Architecture: x86-64
```

How to know if SELINUX is enalbe ? Should it be enable or disable ?

Comment: You need to talk to your VPS provider to enable VPN capability for you: http://wiki.openvz.org/VPN_via_the_TUN/TAP_device

Comment: What type of virtualization does your hosting provider use? If it's a container-based VPS, you should write to support. Seems like some kernel modules isn't loaded.

Comment: Yeah, I thinked about it but he answered me than everything is enable...
How can I check if it's true ?

Comment: They use virtualizor for management but behind that I don't know maybe OpenVZ

Comment: Is selinux enabled?

Comment: Please run the command `hostnamectl`. Look for the `Virtualization:` result.

Comment: So Selinux should be enable ?